# Password is not ASCII error in Spring property file encoding with jasypt

Tags: java, linux, spring-mvc, tomcat8, jasypt

I am getting below error when trying to start tomcat.

**Environment**

- AWS Linux
- Java 8 / Tomcat 8
- Spring MVC application
- jasypt Encryption

**setenv.sh**

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djasypt.encryptor.password=mypassword"
```

**Spring property file**

```
spring.datasource.password=ENC(dfgsdfgsfgsdfgsdfgsd)
```

**Error**

```
 Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:716)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:493)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:469)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:392)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:489)
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.encryptor.DefaultLazyEncryptor.decrypt(DefaultLazyEncryptor.java:81)
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultPropertyResolver.resolvePropertyValue(DefaultPropertyResolver.java:35)
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.resolvePropertyValue(DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySource.getProperty(EncryptablePropertySource.java:16)
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.wrapper.EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper.getProperty(EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper.java:30)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertySourcesPropertyValues.getEnumerableProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyValues.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertySourcesPropertyValues.processEnumerablePropertySource(PropertySourcesPropertyValues.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertySourcesPropertyValues.processPropertySource(PropertySourcesPropertyValues.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertySourcesPropertyValues.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyValues.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getPropertySourcesPropertyValues(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:269)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:329)
    ... 132 more
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKey.<init>(PBEKey.java:64)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKeyFactory.engineGenerateSecret(PBEKeyFactory.java:219)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:336)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:706)
    ... 149 more
```

In windows Environment it works, but not in Linux